# How can I do this with wordpress 3.0.1 (image inside)?

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I need to create a special category for magazine, but I don't know how. Take a look at wireframe image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/sa8Lc.png and hierarchy image -https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWIS3.png for better understanding.

Every image of issue and title like «January 2010» are links to category with articles from magazine of this month. Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: hi, you might want to ask this question at wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done :)

This piece of code from web really help me to do this. Function retrieve IDs of sub-categories from category name.

```
<?php

function subcategories_ids($parent_cat) {
    $parent_id = get_cat_id($parent_cat); //получаем id родительской категории
    $all_cats_ids = get_all_category_ids(); //получаем id ВСЕХ категорий
    sort($all_cats_ids);
    foreach ($all_cats_ids as $cat_id) {
        $temp = true;
        if (cat_is_ancestor_of($parent_id, $cat_id)) {  //проверяем, является ли категория с cat_id дочерней по отношению к $parent_id
            $child_cats_temp[] = $cat_id; //если дочерняя, то добавляем id  во временный массив
            foreach ($child_cats_temp as $parent_temp) { //перебираем поэлементно временный массив
                if (cat_is_ancestor_of($parent_temp, $cat_id)) {
                    $temp = false; //если категория с cat_id является дочерней по отношению к хотя бы одному из элементов временного массива - false
                }
            }
            if ($temp) {
                $child_cats_ids[] = $cat_id;
            }
        }
    }
    return ( $child_cats_ids ); //возвращаем сортированный массив ID подкатегорий
}
?>
```